# Comparing F matrix and E Matrix

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am doing the following:

```
cv::Mat E = cv::findEssentialMat(points1, points2, camera_matrix, cv::RANSAC, 0.99899999, 5);
cv::Mat F = cv::findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, cv::RANSAC, 5);
cv::Mat F_from_E = camera_matrix * E * camera_matrix.t();
F_from_E /= F_from_E.at<double>(2,2);
```

Should not F & F_from_E be identical (at least up to Epsilon)? I am getting total different results.. what is wrong?

F =

```
[7.04979698183469e-06, 0.002432250773974527, -0.4123240414255413;
 -0.002437356457829931, 4.279234351782832e-06, 0.3213949830418951;
 0.4106037007903602, -0.3267400404863846, 1]
```

F_from_E =

```
[-133309825.1056604, -12617730813.88055, -11410224.97616318;
 12698132835.10022, 119029809.7687021, 13590317.66456599;
 11626592.7208607, -13823099.15009778, 1]
```

**Edit:**
After Ash correction, the results are :

F =

```
[5.494144599344668e-06, -0.01010565201781491, 2.173842730409767;
 0.01010172737524295, -7.667916254208621e-06, -1.181814974265482;
 -2.203133830194272, 1.194874769481667, 1]
```

F_from_E =

```
[-6.410384678315267e-07, -8.58589149223806e-06, -0.02103152462240218;
 1.083579227018603e-05, 8.579623497296189e-06, 0.1309687000241576;
 0.02137235887504683, -0.1395666233886129, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your code `F_from_E` should be

```
F_from_E= camera_matrix.inv().t() * E * camera_matrix.inv()
```

That might explain why the magnitude of the elements in your computed `F_from_E` blows up.

**Edit**:

After making the correction in the code as suggested above, it's still natural for the results to differ since you're using RANSAC. Depending on the quality of the matches and the maximum number of iterations, you can have slight to significant differences. Since RANSAC randomly samples matches and keeps the result that has more inliers, it is usually very unlikely that it returns the same result at the end of two distinct runs. However, unless you have too much noise in your data or unless the problem is ill-posed, these solutions will both satisfy the multiview constraints equally well (up to some epsilon).

In your case, you compute `E` using a first RANSAC, and `F` using a second RANSAC. It's thus natural for `F_from_E` and `F` to differ numerically, although I'm almost sure that if you compare their error on your data (**e.g. via `x_1*F*x_2` and `x_1*F_from_E*x_2`) you'll see that they are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are correct. Now the results are much closer but still not identical. I am going to edit my question

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You're welcome. Regarding your still differing results, I think they are to be expected. I edited my answer with an explanation.